# how to click a checkbox that pops up a window AND checks the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, popup

I'm using bpop for a nice pop up window that pops up when I click a checkbox. But I can't figure out how to also check the checkbox.

I've got a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zqk3eeeo/

I figure it's code something like:
   `if($(this).is(':checked'))` 
but I can't figure out where to put it to get it to work.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place it inside the click handler for the button.  Note that I commented out the e.preventDefault() function.  That call prevented the checkbox from becoming "checked".

```
       $('#my-button5').on('click', function(e)  {

            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
            //e.preventDefault();

            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            if ($(this).is(":checked")){
                $('#element_to_pop_up_5').bPopup();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Very much, Terry! That's exactly what I needed. I did try putting the checked code there, but I missed commenting out the prevent function. (And I'm esp.  glad you were so quick to respond since it looks like I didn't submit the question properly!) Thanks again!